# Como corrigir o erro: cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator) utilizando Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Estou tentando enviar um JSON ao meu método Spring para inserção no banco de dados mas recebo a seguinte mensagem:

JSON parse error:

```
Cannot construct instance of br.com.marketHubServer.model.Collaborator (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of br.com.marketHubServer.model.Collaborator (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 6, column: 9]
```

Acredito que o problema aconteça devido a herança de classes que estou fazendo, pois com outras classes o erro não acontece.

Classe Perfil:

```
@Entity(name="Profile")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
        include=JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property="type")
@JsonTypeName("profile")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name="company", value=Company.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name="collaborator", value=Collaborator.class)})
public abstract class Profile {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Transient
    @JsonProperty("type")
    private final String type = "profile";

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String emailAddress;

    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    @Transient
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String newPassword;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<String> permissions;
```

Classe empresa:

```
@Entity
public class Company extends Profile {
    @Transient
    @JsonProperty("type") 
    private final String type = "company";

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String companyLegalName;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 400)
    private String companyDescription;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 14)
    private String companyCnpjCpf;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 9)
    private String companyPhone;
```

Classe Colaborador:

```
@Entity
public class Collaborator extends Profile { 
    @Transient
    @JsonProperty("type")
    private final String type = "collaborator";

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 11)
    private String collaboratorCpf;
```

Método para consistir perfil no banco de dados:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/companies", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Profile create(@AuthenticationPrincipal ProfileAut profileAut, @RequestBody Profile profile) throws Exception {
        profile.setId(0);

        Profile profileSave = companyDAO.save(profile);
        return profileSave;
    }
```

Estou tentando salvar um colaborador no banco de dados através do seguinte json:

```
{
    "emailAddress":"teste",
    "password":"teste2",
    "name":"teste3",
    "type":"collaborator",
    "collaboratorCpf": "teste"
}
```

Sem utilização de herança consegui receber o objeto e armazenar os dados no banco de dados sem problemas.

Comment: Verifique se este artigo pode te ajudar: https://medium.com/consulner/lombok-tricks-and-common-mistakes-fbf0ed044c3c . Leia a partir de "Jackson serialisation and deserialisation".

Comment: Você criou os construtores privados nas Entidades? O Jackson precisa dos contrutores.

Comment: Tentei sim, mas mesmo assim não funcionou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O recomendável para desenvolver a aplicação evitando o máximo possível de herança priorizando sim as composições devidos as boas praticas e etc, você deve refletir o impacto dessa estrutura, se esse requisito é necessário pois realmente gera alguns demandas a mais para gerar o json.

Para utilizar a herança que você deve fazer o mapeamento utilizando o objectMapper do spring

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enableDefaultTyping();
// ... seus profiles poulados

String jsonDataString = mapper.writeValueAsString(profiles);
mapper.readValue(jsonDataString, Profile.class);
```

outro "problema" é que caso você queira retornar os objetos persistidos será necessário deserializar ou seja você deve "remontar o objeto".

```
Profile profiles = mapper.readValue(jsonDataString, Profile.class);
assertThat(profiles.get(0), instanceOf(Company.class));
```

post de referencia : https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance

ps: Existe também uma terceira forma para relacionamento com varias entidades e com varias heraças onde são feitas consultas retornando um `Map<string,object>` sendo assim remontando em Dto's com todos os valores que são necessários.

Answer (score -1):

Eu já tive esse problema com kotlin e o corrigi utilizando o código a baixo.

```
@Configuration
open class JacksonMapper {

    @Bean
    open fun mapper(): ObjectMapper {
        val mapper = ObjectMapper()
        ...

        mapper.registerModule(KotlinModule())
        return mapper
    }
}
```